# Using an object property as the $maxDistance argument in a mongodb geolocation query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, geolocation

I would like to write a $near query with a $maxDistance argument whose value is not constant.  For example, I have a collection of fire stations with a location and a coverage radius, and I want to find all fire stations whose coverage radius includes some specific point.  The coverage radius can vary by station.

I have a collection full of documents that look like:

```
{
    'loc' : [-72,40],
    'radius' : 10
}
```

A query that looks something like:

```
{'loc': { $near : coordinates, $maxDistance : 'radius'}};
```

But that isn't correct.

If I were writing a SQL query, I would use something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table AS foo WHERE foo.radius ... (whatever your distance method looks like)
```

But I can't figure out how to access that radius variable in a mongo query. Is this even possible?

Comment: Can you explain your final goal so that I can perhaps provide you with alternatives?

Comment: Going with the fire station example, I want to end up with a list of all stations foo whose foo.loc is within foo.radius of some specified location.

As far as alternatives, if it's not the sort of thing I can do with a single query, I figure I'll just fetch everything and do the distance comparison myself.  The number of documents I'm going to end up with is actually pretty small, so this should perform reasonably.

Comment: Please add that info to the question, and not just as a comment. But I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't quite do this like this — in general you can not base anything in your MongoDB queries on values in the collections.

However, since MongoDB 2.4 we support a new index called `2dsphere` which allows you to store not only points in the database, but polygons as well. You'd store that information in a document like:

```
db.so.ensureIndex( { loc: '2dsphere' } );
db.so.insert( {
    name: "Firestation 1",
    loc: {
        type: "Polygon",
        coordinates: [ [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 0 ], [ 0, 0 ] ] ]
    }
} );
```

And then you can use an "intersect" query to figure out whether a point is covered by each of the polygons:

```
db.so.find( {
    'loc' : {  
        $geoIntersects: { 
            $geometry: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ 0, 0 ] } 
        } 
    }
} );
```

Which then returns:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("51f24d566775068ab0b786f0"), 
    "name" : "Firestation 1", 
    "loc" : { 
        "type" : "Polygon", 
        "coordinates" : [  [  [  0,  0 ],  [  0,  1 ],  [  1,  1 ],  [  1,  0 ],  [  0,  0 ] ] ] 
    } 
}
```

Here it finds the fire station, because 0, 0 is in the middle of the polygon. Now the trick is of course to calculate the polygon points that make up a circle that is "radius" (say 10km) away from the centre point. You won't be able to get a real circle, but a hexagon or octagon should be good enough. The maths for that isn't extremely simple, but http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html#destPoint has an example in JavaScript.
Just loop your bearing in 8 steps from 0 to 2PI to calculate the points along the circumference of the circle, and put those in the coordinates. Make sure to embed them in a doubly nested array and make the first and the last one the same:

```
{
    name: "Firestation 1",
    loc: {
        type: "Polygon",
        coordinates: [ [
            [ point1-lon, point1-lat ], 
            [ point2-lon, point2-lat ], 
            [ point3-lon, point3-lat ], 
            ...
            [ point1-lon, point1-lat ], 
        ] ]
    }
}
```